# Encrypting PDF with iText to disallow content copying and printing

Tags: java, encryption, itext

I tried this code to encrypt my PDF so users cannot copy content from the PDF (just for testing, I know there's something as OCR'ing :p)

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class EncryptPDF {

private static final String INPUT_FILENAME = "/tmp/test.pdf";
private static final String OUTPUT_FILENAME = "/tmp/test_encrypted.pdf";
private static final String USER_PASSWORD = "";
private static final String OWNER_PASSWORD = "foobar";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PdfReader reader = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    PdfStamper stamper = null;

    try {
        // Define input
        reader = new PdfReader(INPUT_FILENAME);

        // Define output
        out = new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILENAME);

        // Encrypt document
        stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, out);
        stamper.setEncryption(USER_PASSWORD.getBytes(), OWNER_PASSWORD.getBytes(), ~(PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY | PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING), PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_128);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (stamper != null) {
            try {
                stamper.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

... But when I open the PDF, I can still select content from it. I'm using iText 5.0.2.

Any idea's on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please also supply the PDF you generated.

Comment: Simply supplying only the permissions that you want to allow instead of negating the OR-ed together permissions could do it. Why do you use negation there?

Comment: @mkl: this is the one you can use: http://www.selab.isti.cnr.it/ws-mate/example.pdf

Comment: @owlstead: I tried using PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS (no negating), which is giving me the same problem ...

Comment: @JochenHebbrecht I'll look into that tomorow in office. But have you tried what happens if you allow nothing? Screen readers do some kind of text extraction, too...

Comment: @mkl: when I pass the value "0" to the stamper, the same problem occurs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I run your code, I get a 0 byte file and `NullPointerException` during `stamper.close()` --- which is quite natural as you first close the `PdfReader` and afterwards the `PdfStamper`, but the latter `close()` method accesses the `PdfReader` (already closed now) for its work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment to the question, running the example code as is results in a `NullPointerException` during `stamper.close()` --- which is quite natural as you first close the `PdfReader` and afterwards the `PdfStamper,` but the latter `close()` method accesses the `PdfReader` (already closed now) for its work.

When I run your code with the order of closing the `PdfReader` and the `PdfWriter` reversed, though, I get a proper result file with the access rights as required:

[image: document properties of protected PDF showing print and copy as disabled]

PS: I'm using iText version 5.3.5; if reversing the order of the `close()` calls does not help in your case, you may want to update from your version 5.0.2.

Comment: I was not getting the NPE with 5.0.2, but I do get it with 5.3.5. I'm still failing to encrypt the PDF because of this error:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive. I will Google tonight for a solution for this problem

Comment: Which Bouncycastles JARs are you using?

Comment: Nevermind, got it working with: bcprov-jdk14-1.47.jar and bcprov-ext-jdk14-1.47.jar

Comment: Yes, the required BC version changed from 1.46 to 1.47 in some 5.3.x version. Furthermore I guess that while you didn't get a NPE with iText 5.0.2, stamper.close() nonetheless failed silently to stamp properly on a closed PdfReader.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answers and tremendous help! You rock mkl :-)!